# Removing drop down menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have created a menu in html that slides down from behind the header. Al, this works perfectly. I click the button the menu the menu slides down click it again it slides up.
I was wondering is there a way I could add a rollout function to this.
I have tried but the menu consists of various columns where the data is brought from php.
I added a rollover the main page which worked but sometimes stopped the initial drop as the mouse was allready over the page.
I was thinking would it be possible to add this function to any other element on the page that isn't the menu or the contained divs within the menu, when the menu is down and then remove the function to return the menu when the menu is returned.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="nav_btn_drop_down" onclick="toggle_menu(this,'clothing',menu_toggle)"><a>CLOTHING&nbsp;<img src="global.includes/small_icon_down.png" width="10" height="10"  /></a></div>

var menu_toggle = false;
    function toggle_menu(f,s,t){
        if(t === false){
            document.getElementById('menu').style.opacity = 1;
            $('#menu').fadeIn(1,function(){         
                $('#menu').animate({height:menu_height+"px"},750);
            });
            menu_toggle = true;
        }else{
            menu_toggle = false;
            $('#menu').animate({height:"0px"},750,function(){
                document.getElementById('menu').style.opacity = 0;
                $('#menu').fadeOut(1,function(){});
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding "...add a rollout function..."?

Comment: if the mouse moves out of the boundaries of the drop down section